# no such column: task_date (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

no such column: task_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tasks_table WHERE task_status = ? OR task_status = ? ORDER BY task_date

проверил код много разок и не смог найти ошибку

DBHelper

```html
 

   public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reminder_database";

        public static final String TASKS_TABLE = "tasks_table";

        public static final String TASK_TITLE_COLUMN = "task_title";
        public static final String TASK_DATE_COLUMN = "task_date";
        public static final String TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN = "task_priority";
        public static final String TASK_STATUS_COLUMN = "task_status";
        public static final String TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN = "task_time_stamp";

        private static final String TASKS_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT =  "CREATE TABLE "
                + TASKS_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TASK_TITLE_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + TASK_DATE_COLUMN + " LONG, " + TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN + " INTEGER, "
                + TASK_STATUS_COLUMN + " INTEGER, " + TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN + " LONG);";


        public static final String SELECTION_STATUS = DBHelper.TASK_STATUS_COLUMN + " = ?";
        public static final String SELECTION_TIME_STAMP = TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN + " = ?";

        private DBQueryManager dbQueryManager;
        private DBUpdateManager dbUpdateManager;



        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            dbQueryManager = new DBQueryManager(getReadableDatabase());
            dbUpdateManager = new DBUpdateManager(getWritableDatabase());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TASKS_TABLE_CREATE_SCRIPT);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TASKS_TABLE);
             onCreate(db);
        }

        public void saveTask(ModelTask task){

            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

            newValues.put(TASK_TITLE_COLUMN,task.getTitle());
            newValues.put(TASK_DATE_COLUMN,task.getDate());
            newValues.put(TASK_STATUS_COLUMN,task.getStatus());
            newValues.put(TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN,task.getPriority());
            newValues.put(TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN, task.getTimeStamp());

            getWritableDatabase().insert(TASKS_TABLE, null, newValues);

        }

        public DBUpdateManager update() {
            return dbUpdateManager;
        }

        public DBQueryManager query() {
            return dbQueryManager;
        }

        public void removeTask(long timeStamp){
            getWritableDatabase().delete(TASKS_TABLE,SELECTION_TIME_STAMP,new String[]{Long.toString(timeStamp)});

        }
    }
```

DBQueryManager

```
ublic class DBQueryManager {
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    public DBQueryManager(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        this.sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteDatabase;
    }


    public ModelTask getTask(long timeStamp){
        ModelTask modelTask = null;
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(DBHelper.TASKS_TABLE,null,DBHelper.SELECTION_TIME_STAMP,
                new String[]{Long.toString(timeStamp)},null,null,null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){

            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE_COLUMN));
            long date =  c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_DATE_COLUMN));
            int priority = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN));
            int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_STATUS_COLUMN));
            modelTask = new ModelTask(title,date,priority,status,timeStamp);

        }
        c.close();
        return modelTask;

    }


    public List<ModelTask> getTask(String selection , String[] selectionArgs,String orderBy){
        List<ModelTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(DBHelper.TASKS_TABLE, null,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,orderBy);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {

                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE_COLUMN));
                long date =  c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_DATE_COLUMN));
                int priority = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN));
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_STATUS_COLUMN));
                long timeStamp = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TASK_TIME_STAMP_COLUMN));

                ModelTask modelTask = new ModelTask(title,date,priority,status,timeStamp);
                tasks.add(modelTask);



            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return tasks;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам надо сделать :
1. - изменить код создания таблицы на

```
CREATE TABLE "tasks_table" (
    `_ID`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `task_title`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `task_date` INTEGER,
    `task_priority` INTEGER,
    `task_status`   INTEGER,
    `task_time_stamp`   INTEGER
)
```

2. переделать запрос `

```
> SELECT * FROM tasks_table WHERE task_status = ? OR task_status = ?
> ORDER BY task_date
```

` на

```
 `SELECT * FROM tasks_table WHERE task_status = ? ORDER BY task_date;`
```

Я думаю Вам поможет мой совет

Comment: так же в WHERE task_status = ? OR task_status = ? ORDER BY task_date, Вы пытаетесь сделать выборку между двумя одинаковыми солонками с неизвестными переменными и еще хотите это все отсортировать. База не понимает Ваш запрос, возможно надо изменить (или убрать ) одну колонку из запроса

Comment: дело точно не в ```WHERE```  и ```Order By```, у меня запрос с аналогичными условиями работает прекрасно.

Comment: я имел ввиду убрать одну из колонок task_status = ? в запросе

Comment: С двумя колонками тоже все ок

Comment: нашел решение , проблема в том что если я добавлю столбец к таблице, то  структура база данных меняется и надо увеличить версию базы данных так, как я вызываю метод onUpgrade () , который будет добавить столбец к таблице. Всякий раз, когда изменяется структура сделаны в базу данных, версия должна быть увеличен, так что соответствующие обратные вызовы инициируются для БД SQLite для воссоздания таблицы с новыми полями / столбцов.                                                                                              public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

Comment: Рад, что все решилось